# what are the minimum steps to run in order to see the updates after edit a php file from the vendor folder

Tags: magento2, cache, code-generation, vendor

somehow in my

> /public_html/vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/ResourceModel/Product/Indexer/Price/BatchSizeCalculator.php

file there are extra characters accidentally added by one of the team member that creates error when indexing. I removed the extra characters, but i don't see the changes when i try to reindex on the production site.

What are the minimum steps to see the updates i made to that BatchSizeCalculator.php file in the vendor folder?

running php bin/magento c:c and php bin/magento c:f didn't work
I'm trying to stay away from running setup:upgrade setup:di:compile or s:s:d if it is not necessary.

Is there an corresponding file in the generated folder or var folder that i can apply the same update without running the above commands?